# Displaying A List of Available WIFI networks in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have been trying to get a list of `ScanResult`, but without success.

Attached here is my code:

```
public class listenerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String netSsid;
    ListView groups;
    EditText filter;
    WifiManager wifi;
    String wifis[];
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    Button refreshGroups;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listener);
        groups = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled. making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
         wifi.startScan();
    }

private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                wifis[i] = wifiScanList.get(i).toString();
        }
        groups.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.adapte_layout, (wifiScanList.size() > 0 ? wifis : new String[]{"No net available"})));
    }
}
```

And here in my manifest.xml (part of the permissions):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

This is not working.

I will be very glad for your help (and I'm sorry for my English).
Thanks!!

Comment: what is the problem? Does it just not return anything. Please be more explicit. What have you validated from the perspective of the taht it should work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

At first look i thought that you are not getting results at all.
 But your code is fine it retrieves the ScanResult. The only problem is with your ArrayAdapter. As you have not attached layout xmls it is difficult to know what is not working exactly.
Anyways i have used the default layout for Adapter. Here is the code you need to change to see the result in the screen

```
groups.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, (wifiScanList.size() > 0 ? wifis : new String[]{"No net available"})));
```